# viewController insertSubview:atIndex

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 viewControllers, AViewController contents 3 buttons at the bottom,BViewController contents a tableView. In AViewController the time click one button,`[aViewController insertSubview:bViewController.view atIndex:0]`, both views display correctly, but when I scroll the tableView,app crashed.
Any problem I made?

Comment: What did the crash log say?

Comment: insertSubview:atIndex: isn't a view controller method. Please show your actual code and the crash log.

Comment: It sounds like that you release the UI Element too early and then there are no action linked on the object any more. I guess the crash logs say "exec bad access"

Comment: @VinhTran thanks, you are right, I used `autoRelease` for bViewController.

Comment: Show your code. There is no `autoRelease` method in the iOS SDK. (There is `autorelease` though, but if you mean that you should write that too)